# Serial connection falling out of sync. Ardunio and C# connection

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple app where an Ardunio sends read data to the C# program using simple serial.write()'s. I send the data from Ardunio with special syntax and the c# program reads and interprets it and eventually graphs the data.

For example, the Ardunio program sends data

```
Serial.write("DATA 1 3 90;");
```

which means: X value and Y value in chart 1 is 3 and 90 respectively.
And the c# program reads it using

```
private async void Serialport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    await serialport.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);

    await Task.Run(() => Graph()); // Graph function graphs the data


}
```

In the `graph()` function, I convert the buffer to a string with `Encode.ASCII.GetString(buffer);` and interpret the data with the syntax and stuff. But for some reason either the c# program doesn't read it fast enough or the Arduino doesn't send it fast enough and the messages are sometimes interrupted For example the packet I received is:

DATA 2 5 90;DATA 5 90 10;DATA 1 1         <|-------- I cannot get the last Y Value

And the next data module starts with

75;DATA 5 4 60;DATA 14 5 6;DATA
  /\

|

+==================== It is here

BTW, all the packets are 32 bytes.

So I either need to get the data line by line but I cannot do that because ardunio sends it too fast

```
 Serial.write("DATA 1 3 90;");
 Serial.write("DATA 2 4 40;");
```

Comes to C# as DATA 1 3 90;DATA 2 4 40; as a whole block.
Or I need to get it all at once?

(I prefer getting it line by line)

UPDATE:

When delay(1000); is added between sends. The data is processed correctly. Without the delays, Arduino sends the data too fast, and data clumps and interrupted. How can I make sure that there is no delay in the data yet the data is reliable and without interruption?

UPDATE 2:

When buffer size is increased to 100 * 1024 * 1024 as well as the readCount in ReadAsync method, the read message is much larger still with interruptions tho.

I can give you any extra information.

PS. I didn't give the whole code because it is a large block. But I can give it piece by piece if you tell me where you want it.

Any help is appreciated.